# How to wrap $digest()?

Tags: angularjs

I need to measure $digest duration inside my Angular application (performance monitoring).

Ideally, I would like to take time just before starting `$digest()` and and another one just after it executed.

I planned to wrap `$digest` function with my code, something like this (pseudo code):

```
function $digest(){

  1. take timestamp
  2. call to original $digest()
  3. take timestamp
}
```

This wrapping should be transparent to the rest of the application, so everyone just keep call `$scope.$digest()` without any knowledge about this wrap. I want to avoid any modifications to `angular.js`

Question: how I can do this? [Using Angular 1.3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override $digest in the prototype of rootScope.

```
angular.module('myModule', []).run(run);

function run($rootScope) {
    var scopeProto = Object.getPrototypeOf($rootScope);
    var originalDigest = scopeProto.$digest;
    scopeProto.$digest = function(){
        console.log("Hello from digest!");
        originalDigest.call(this);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgyh30v7/) (open console to see result).

Comment: Was not aware about 'Object.getPrototypeOf()'. Great patent, thanks!